# JSpinner default changes years instead of days

Tags: java, swing, date, awt, jspinner

Problem: When `dateSpin` arrow is clicked the spinner changes years instead of days. I would like to make it default so only days are changed + make it so the user cannot enter his own input into the spinner field.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class Test1 extends JFrame 
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Test1 frame1 = new Test1();
    frame1.setVisible(true);
}

public Test1()
{
    super("Test");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    setSize(300,300);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner();
    Date date = new Date();
    spinner.setModel(new SpinnerDateModel(date, null, null, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

    JSpinner.DateEditor dateEditor = new JSpinner.DateEditor(spinner, "yyyy/MM/dd");

    spinner.setEditor(dateEditor);

    add(spinner);

   }

}
```

In oracle docs this problem is mentioned:

> Note, however, that some types of look and feel ignore the specified field, and instead change the field that appears selected.

However, as I am not fluent in Java I don't understand how to fix this.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: I just made an MCVE in which in both Windows LAF & (default) Metal look and feels, the year changed first because it was the number in focus. When arrow through to the day, the up/down buttons changed the day.

Comment: That way i have to manipulate it and change the date layout once i upload it into csv file. I guess i could go that way, but just thought that maybe there was an obvious solution. Maybe focusing on days right away?

Comment: No, I actually took out that part of the comment about moving the day to first part because I tried it and it shows quite bizarre behaviour of changing the day & year at the same time! :P Try it yourself..

Comment: oh... ok :) i believe its possible to change via constructing custom model, but that seems way to cumbersome for such a little thing.

Comment: *"..that seems way to cumbersome for such a little thing."* That's why they pay programmers the 'big bucks'..

Comment: if i understood spinners constructor i would actually do it, but after re-reading oracle documentation several times i still don't get it :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a good solution, but you could just make sure that the caret position of the textfield is always at the end (the fact that you want the spinner to be uneditable maybe makes this technique a bit more tolerable):

```
dateEditor.getTextField().setEditable(false);
dateEditor.getTextField().addCaretListener(new CaretListener() {
    @Override
    public void caretUpdate(CaretEvent e) {
        int pos = dateEditor.getTextField().getDocument().getLength();
        if (e.getDot() != pos) {
            dateEditor.getTextField().setCaretPosition(pos);
        }
    }
});
```

---

This worked for me using the following LaFs: `Metal`, `Nimbus`, `Motif`, `Windows`, `Windows Classic`. (That's all the LaFs I can test right now)